# "off topic" en castellano

Tags: traducción

`"Off topic"` es un término que se usa regularmente hoy en día, preferentemente en temas informáticos pero cada vez más en temas más generales. Sin embargo, no deja de ser un anglicismo al que creo que debería corresponderle algún término equivalente en castellano.

¿Cuál sugieren? Leyendo [el artículo de Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off_topic) no encuentro ninguna, pero en [Wordreference](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=off%20topic) veo `"que no viene al caso"` o `"sin relación al tema"`.

Comment: En algunos foros en los que participé se usaba “desvirtuar” con el sentido de _being off-topic_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yo propongo la expresión:

> Fuera de [ámbito](http://lema.rae.es/drae2001/srv/search?key=%C3%A1mbito)

Funcionaría bien en un contexto como este foro, donde puedes cerrar una pregunta porque está `fuera de(l) ámbito` del sitio. Es una expresión un poco más corta ya sencilla que "No viene al caso" o "Sin relación con el tema" o incluso "está fuera de lugar" (una de las propuestas en el enlace a *Wordreference* que aporta la pregunta, y que puede tener otras connotaciones distintas a *off topic*).

Comment: A little more colloquial, but still correct, would be "fuera de lugar".  It means roughly the same thing as "fuera de ámbito".

Comment: @WalterMitty, true, but it also has some other connotations, like after a racist joke: "Ese comentario sobre los negros está fuera de lugar". That why I though that "Fuera de ámbito" would work better. It expresses the same but doesn't have the connotations of potentially being offensive.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.  It really means "out of place".  I added an answer that points to a phrase "fuera de tema", that I found in Wikipedia español.

Comment: *Fuera de tema* es la expresión que yo usaría. Sin embargo, como *fuera de lugar*, también tiene otras connotaciones. En mi dialecto *irse de tema* puede equivaler a "pasarse de la raya".

Comment: off topic is not about a site.

Answer (score 9):

En mi caso, yo usualmente uso:

> Fuera de contexto

Ejemplo:

> ¡Lo que tratas de decir está fuera de contexto!

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo en mi caso, español de Chile.

Comment: En mi caso (Español de España) "Fuera de contexto" también me parece la expresión correcta. "Fuera de ámbito" no suena natural.

Answer (score 5):

En Wikipedia en español, hay un artículo "trol" en lo que se refiere al internet.  En ese artículo, se usa la frase "fuera de tema".

[Ver entrada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trol_(Internet))

Esa frase es un enlace a otro artículo, pero si se hace click, se llega a un artículo en español que sólo usa la palabra "off'topic".  Interesante.

Comment: wikipedia in this case is not a correct source, please, follow the other answers, they´re correct and really detailed. "Aparte" is a composite word noting the different new topic, so just by putting in the "aparte diría esto otro", it´s enough for us... But online politeness is not the discussion here because in some online forums you should explicitly invoke the "Offtopic" or else

Answer (score 3):

"Off topic" en español está relacionado con algo que, dentro de un tema determinado, la nueva idea presentada no tiene relación. Esto puede ser de forma permanente o temporal, pero es una idea aparte de lo que principalmente se habla.

La expresión más certera puede escribirse o expresarse de manera oral como "punto aparte".

Por ejemplo: Se habla de un tema determinado y para mencionar algo ocurrido, o algo visto, o cualquier cosa se dice `"punto aparte, el otro día vi un auto..."` y se sigue con la nueva idea, dejando la posibilidad de, posteriormente, retomar la idea anterior.

Esto depende netamente del contexto. Este es un contexto oral, en el escrito también se puede ocupar el mismo término de modo similar.

Answer (score 3):

A no ser que esté hablando en inglés no uso «*off topic*» nunca. 
A parte de las alternativas ya mencionadas se me ocurren las siguientes opciones:

Hacer un **paréntesis**, un **inciso** o una **digresión**.

*Ejemplo:*

Un profesor, hablando a sus alumnos: «Si me lo permitís voy a **hacer un paréntesis** en este tema sobre el modelado kárstico y os voy a contar una simpática anécdota que me pasó a los seis años cerca del yacimiento paleontológico de Quibas...»

**digresión**

Desviación en el hilo de un discurso oral o escrito para expresar algo que se aparta del tema que se está tratando.

**paréntesis**

Oración o elemento incidental o suplementario, sin enlace necesario con los demás miembros del enunciado, cuyo sentido interrumpe y no altera.

**inciso**

Comentario o digresión distinta del tema principal que se intercala en un discurso.

Comment: Bienvenido a Spanish.Se. Gran primer aporte (espero ver muchos más en el futuro). Cómo lo aplicarías la uno de los usos que le damos en este sitio: "Esa pregunta es _off topic_"? Por ejemplo, "Esa pregunta [digrede](https://twitter.com/fundeu/status/685418339175403521?lang=es)"? Parece ser que el verbo existió pero ya no está incluido en el DRAE (interesante!).

Comment: Voto positivo por "digresión". Yo no conocía esa palabra. En cuanto a lo que comenta @Diego, ¿"cometer una digresión"?, ¿"caer en una digresión"? Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Lo mas cercano que conozco en mi idioma que signifique lo que en inglés significa `off topic` es la expresión: "hablando de todo como los locos".

No es una traducción, no es un equivalente, solo contiene el espíritu de la idea. Off Topic: hablando de todo como los locos. Expresa la misma intención.

Comment: Hay otras expresiones, tipo "cambiando de tercio" o "cambiando de tema", pero "off topic" tiene unas connotaciones muy precisas en algunos sitios de Internet. No estás hablando de todo ni cambiando el tema de conversación en un hilo. Es más bien un apunte que no está relacionado con el tema principal. "Hablando de todo como los locos" te vale para introducir algo que es _off topic_, pero si quieres decirle a alguien que algo es _off topic_ la expresión ya no se ajusta tan bien.

Comment: Quizás la expresión "Por cierto..." haga el truco

Answer (score 1):

"**Cambio de tema**" es un término muy común que puede intercambiarse perfectamente.

Por ejemplo:

> Si me permites el cambio de tema, Bla bla bla, bla bla bla.