# ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de traducir "I'm voting to close as off-topic..."?

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, preposiciones, español-neutral

En Stack Overflow en español estamos traduciendo la interfaz para que los textos originales de Stack Overflow en inglés aparezcan en castellano.

Hace unos días, yo propuse que la traducción de:

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because...

Fuera:

> Voto **para** cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque...

Indicando finalidad con la preposición *para*. Sin embargo, distintas personas comentan en [una pregunta en Meta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3104/83) que les resulta extraño el uso de *para* y que ellos apostarían por:

> Voto **por** cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque...

Para dar contexto: esta frase es la que aparece en la interfaz cuando alguien quiere explicar por qué una pregunta debería ser cerrada. Así, la frase final puede ser del tipo *Voto por/para cerrar esta pregunta como tema no relacionado porque es imposible de reproducir*.

Yo usé [*para*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Rp1CuT2) en su acepción:

> 1. prep. Denota el fin o término a que se encamina una acción.

Y se podría objetar que [*por*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TgJ7yhD) puede usarse en este contexto con distintas acepciones:

> 1. prep. Indica el agente en las oraciones en pasiva.
>
> 23. prep. Con ciertos infinitivos, para. Por no incurrir en la censura.

Así pues, ¿cuál sería la forma más normativamente correcta, a la vez que neutra para que suene idiomática para la mayor cantidad de gente hispanohablante?

Comment: Está muy complicado cumplir con todos los requisitos ya que incluyen tanto técnicos como perceptivos sin mencionar el aspecto transitorio.

Comment: Yo creo que se puede defender fácilmente ambas opciones (*voto con el fin de cerrar* --> **para**, *voto eligiendo la opción de cerrar* --> **por**), pero a mi oído *por* suena mejor.

Comment: Como muchas respuestas ya se parecen a lo que quería decir, te expongo mi punto de vista en mi comentario a una respuesta. Escribo este otro comentario para añadir que no termina de sonarme bien la parte "como tema no relacionado", por la palabra "como". Aunque es traducción literal del inglés, no me suena bien en español. Quizá deberíamos usar algo como "por ser tema no relacionado", aunque haya redundancia con el por.

Comment: Votar viene de "hacer un voto" (promesa, compromiso), por eso es naturalmente intransitivo (lo son sus principales acepciones). El voto se hace, como apunta @walen, _a favor_ de una opción o candidato, de ahí que le quede mejor el _por_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yo también escogería **por**, usando la acepción específica para ello:

> **[por](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TgJ7yhD#McPK9qk)**
>
> 11. prep. A favor o en defensa de alguien o de algo.

Tal como [ha comentado Gorpik](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/24031/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-mejor-manera-de-traducir-im-voting-to-close-as-off-topic/24034?noredirect=1#comment39368_24034), este uso coincide con el que apunta el DPD en su entrada para "votar":

> [**votar**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=votar). 1. Como intransitivo, dicho de una persona, ‘dar su voto’. (...) A menudo se especifica el sentido del voto mediante un complemento introducido con ***por***, *a favor de*, *contra* o *en contra de*.

Ejemplos de uso que quizá se vean más naturales: *voto **por** el PACMA; voto **por** dejar el coche aquí e ir andando; voto **por** hacer una votación.*

El uso de *para* sería más bien para explicar el motivo de la votación: *voto **para** elegir un nuevo Gobierno; voto **para** decidir el medio de transporte; voto **para** ver qué hacemos*.

En el caso de SO.es, votas *para* decidir si se cierra la pregunta o no, y de entre las diferentes opciones votas *por* cerrarla como fuera de ámbito<sup>1</sup>.

<sub><sup>1</sup>Traducir *off-topic* como "tema no relacionado" no me parece la mejor opción: algo puede estar relacionado con la temática del sitio y al mismo tiempo estar fuera del ámbito definido del sitio, debido a las normas. Pero eso sería ([y de hecho es](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/13198/off-topic-en-castellano)) otra pregunta.</sub>

Comment: _Fuera de contexto_ o _fuera de ámbito_ son dos de las opciones que surgieron en ["off topic" en castellano](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/13198/1674)

Comment: walen: lo de _fuera de ámbito_ es la decisión que tomaron hace tiempo en SOes para llamar _off topic_, por lo que cambiarlo en esta cadena específica era... fuera de ámbito :P

Comment: El DPH tiene una entrada para *votar* (http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=votar) en la que explica que el sentido del voto se suele introducir mediante *por*, *a favor de*, *contra* o *en contra de*. Pero creo que la explicación que nos da aquí @walen es correcta.

Comment: @walen Perfecto

Comment: tambien podemos añadir que en el uso del "for" y el "to" la accion no esta siendo directa, tu voto no puede ser ejercido "para" algo, pues no se pueden votar las acciones en si, si no las desiciones.

Answer (score 5):

En principio *votar **por** algo* es la forma más habitual en castellano y ésa es la que yo preferiría. *Votar **para** algo* no es una frase tan habitual. Me imagino que uno podría usarla para expresar cosas como "voto para que los políticos escuchen de una vez el mensaje de la ciudadanía". Es decir, de alguna forma *votar para* expresa que el voto es un medio para algún fin **que no es la elección en sí**.

El único problema que le veo a *votar por* es de detalle. Suena como si toda pregunta tuviese por defecto una votación abierta, y uno debiese elegir alguna de las opciones. Pero esto ya es buscarle la quinta pata al gato y para mí no es realmente una objeción.

Comment: Quizás la mejor cosa en este contexto sea simplemente evitar por completo el verbo *votar*.  La acción es *cerrar*, y como texto podría decir con igual o más sentido «Quiero cerrar esta pregunta porque…» o «Esta pregunta debe cerrarse por…», «Sumo mi opinión/voto/voz a que esta pregunta se cierre por…».   Sensu strictissimo, votamos *para* cerrar una pregunta *por* alguna razón (como dices, no hay otra opción), cosa que suena rarísimo.

Answer (score 0):

*Voto **por** cerrar la pregunta por no conformarse a las normas del sitio.*

(Con el enlace que explica cómo hacer una pregunta bien planteada.)

*I detest word-for-word, literal translations.  They feel like having to walk home every day along a tropical unpaved street whose mud gets thicker and stickier with each passing day of rain.  I think it's better to load the* idea *into one's head and then experiment freely with natural ways of expressing the essential ideas.*

---

Voy a votar para que se haga cierta acción.

Voy a votar por fulano o por tal propuesta.

Justificación: así lo aprendí, y una búsqueda con google apoya este esquema también.

Comment: ¿Pero por qué sugieres __por__ y no __para__?

Comment: @fedorqui - Ya agregué algo.  Perdón, cuando contesté la pregunta, creí que estábamos en Meta donde nomás había que votar por alguna de las dos opciones.

Comment: En efecto, tomando "votar" como un verbo similar a "optar", usaría "votar por"= elegir (eso), mientras que "votar para" se entiende de otra forma. En ella, "para" haría referencia a la acción de votar, y no al contenido del voto; es decir, "ejercer el voto para conseguir un objetivo", y el método seria "votando por la propuesta".

Comment: @aparente001 I don't think you can say "conformarse **con**" to mean "meet / comply with / adjust/stick to". I think you should say "conformarse a" or, much better, "estar de acuerdo con/conforme a / adaptarse/ajustarse a".

Comment: Deleting my answer because it doesn't contribute anything the other two don't have.